# Awstats tool : issue with missing icons and histogram bars on main page of Awstats - probably an issue of path defined into Apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, icons, cgi, awstats

I meet difficulties to make appear with awstats tool (CGI script), icons and associated histogram bars, on one of my website (dubbed here `website.com`).

The issue is pretty tricky since I am using different RewriteCond and RewriteRules to get `http://www.website.com, http://website.com, https://www.website.com` redirections to `https://website.com` target.

Moreover, the task is more complex because I have a Zope server after Apache.

So, to summarize, here below all these rewritecond and rewriterules which produce what is expected, i.e all redirections to `https://website.com` and access by password to the `awstats` tool. Everything is working fine except the fact that icons and histograms are  missing in main page of `awstats` once this latter is loaded:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    # Test local
    ServerAdmin admin@website.com
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com 

    # LOG
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    # ACTIVATE SSL
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/chain.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    # www to non www for HTTPS
    # checking for the same thing again
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    # some people might argue second redirect here is excessive since you already arrived at correct host, but I'd leave this for you to sort out
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
    # your /cgi-bin checks can be merged into one regex 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/(search|awstats) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]

    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    #CacheDisable *

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"
    Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
    Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/fdoc/awstats/examples/css"

<Files "awstats.pl">
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Satisfy any
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Advanced Web Statistics"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/awstats-users.pwd
        Require valid-user
</Files>

<Directory "/usr/share/awstats/icon">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am not an expert about the CGI scripts and their alias. All the icons are located into `/usr/share/awstats/icon/` directory.

Where is my error?

**UPDATE 1 :**

0) I realized that `Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"` and 
    `Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"` don't seem to be necessary,   but for `Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"`, this is necessary.

However, this is an issue of `CSS` but I think the most important file is the directory of icons.

1) I have found and installed the package `awstats_7.6` for `Debian 10 Buster`.

Now, all files (plugin, lib, lang etc ...) are located into `/usr/share/awstats/`

For the moment, I have further informations from `Apache2` logs. When I reload the `awstats` page (reachable from `https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl`) , I get into `access.log` :

```
    100.87.10.76 - - [02/Apr/2020:01:20:06 +0200] "GET /awstats-icon/browser/notavailable.png HTTP/1.1" 404 434 "https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
    100.87.10.76 - - [02/Apr/2020:01:20:06 +0200] "GET /awstats-icon/other/hx.png HTTP/1.1" 404 434 "https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
    100.87.10.76 - - [02/Apr/2020:01:20:06 +0200] "GET /awstats-icon/other/he.png HTTP/1.1" 404 434 "https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
    ... etc
```

I have put `etc` to mean all the list of icons missing.

2) Moreover, I have this message at the top once I load awstats main page :

[image]

Conclusion : I don't know anymore what to try. However, from the `1)` part above, I have explicitely indicated in Apache2 config file :

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon"
```

with permissions :

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  2 16:25 /usr/share/awstats/icon/
```

3) Finally, I think  the most interesting information comes from the `error.log` of Apache2 :

```
[Thu Apr 02 01:37:04.344047 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 19209] proxy_util.c(2578): [client 100.87.10.76:40246] AH00947: connected /++vh++https:website.com:443/++/awstats-icon/other/hh.png to localhost:8443, referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
[Thu Apr 02 01:37:04.600404 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 19209] proxy_util.c(2316): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (*)
```

**This shows  the conflicts between the path of `Virtualhost from Zope` and the path of `CGI scripts` from `Apache2`, especially with the first line :**

```
/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/awstats-icon/other/hh.png to localhost:8443, referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
```

What do you think about all these clues ?

**UPDATE 2:** Following the suggestion of `@Tom Hundt`, I generate a deeper analysis into log rewrite. Below is what I get when I load the `awstats` main page.

```
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057073 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/awstats-icon/other/hx.png', referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057093 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/awstats-icon/other/hx.png', referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057107 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] rewrite '/awstats-icon/other/hx.png' -> 'https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/awstats-icon/other/hx.png', referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057120 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] forcing proxy-throughput with https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/awstats-icon/other/hx.png, referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057131 2020] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/awstats-icon/other/hx.png [OK], referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
```

It seems an interesting line is :

```
[Sun Apr 05 16:17:01.057073 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 25288] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 31.11.12.101:51422] 31.11.12.101 - - [website.com/sid#7fa0b5d01d98][rid#7fa0ba0930a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/awstats-icon/other/hx.png', referer: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?framename=mainright
```

It is indicated that pattern `'^/(.*)'` is applied to to `uri '/awstats-icon/other/hx.png'`.

So I conclude that my isssue since the beginning comes from the rewrite rules I apply on URL with cgi-bin directory, i.e when I do :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/(search|awstats) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]
```

Do you agree ?

Comment: Please refrain from adding "regards" to the end of your posts. Readers generally prefer technical writing here. Please have mercy on the volunteer editors here - there are not many of us, and there is too much material that needs improvement. Thank you.

Comment: I sometimes give this advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current config prevents proxying for /cgi-bin/ with the RewriteCond here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/(search|awstats) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]
```

You need also short-circuit for /awstats* so they aren't proxied to that zope nonsense.
Multiple conditions are AND'ed by default so it's easy:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/awstats [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/(search|awstats) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `quotes`, if this doesn't fix your issue check for apache `error log`

```
Alias "/awstatsclasses" "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"
Alias "/awstats-icon" "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
Alias "/awstatscss" "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"
```

Comment: it does nothing. You can see my **UPDATE 1** where I give more informations about my issue.

Comment: can you test your code without the `rewrite` rules and `https`, duplicate the file and use it on `localhost`, just test the `aliases` you have if they work

Comment: your suggestion implies too many modifications since I am using a VPS and so can't put http://localhost instead of http://website.com

Comment: what is this then? RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]??, good luck to you

Comment: localhost in this way refers to the distant VPS localhost, not the localhost of my computer from which I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Turn on logging for `mod_rewrite` temporarily.

In `http.conf` put:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

and then (optionally) in your shell you can do

```
tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'
```

to help figure out what is happening.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have put an **UPDATE2**, could you take a look at this please ?